# Оформление эпиграфа (2)

Tags: цитата, оформление-текста

Если эпиграф взят из народного творчества, как указывается авторство? (Народная песня?)
А если автор берёт эпиграфом свои же слова, нужна ли подпись под эпиграфом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, если эпиграф из народного творчества, указывается только жанр: народная песня, солдатская песня, свадебная песня, пословица.

Эпиграф к главе XIV «Капитанской дочки» Пушкина:

Мирская молва —
Морская волна.
              (Пословица)

Раньше ссылка бралась в скобки, современное требование - без скобок и без точки.

Если автор берёт эпиграфом свои же слова,  подпись под эпиграфом не ставится, но делается указание, откуда взята цитата или когда это сказано и где. Например, вот автоэпиграф А.Ахматовой к "Реквиему":

В страшные годы ежовщины я провела семнадцать месяцев в тюремных очередях в Ленинграде. Как-то раз кто-то «опознал» меня. Тогда стоящая за мной женщина с голубыми губами, которая, конечно, никогда не слыхала моего имени, очнулась от свойственного нам всем оцепенения и спросила меня на ухо (там все говорили шёпотом):
— А это вы можете описать?
И я сказала:
— Могу.
Тогда что-то вроде улыбки скользнуло по тому, что некогда было её лицом.
1 апреля 1957, Ленинград